# How to call a specific method on an object after creating it via its constructor using reflection in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection, .net-assembly

I have a WPF application that I want to launch using:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom
```

It works fine but after this, I am trying to call it's default constructor:

```
LayerView.MainWindow();
```

Then, call the `Show` method on the created instance.

I tried using:

```
assembly.GetTypes();
```

Looping through them and then when I find the right type `LayerView.MainWindow`, then call:

```
c.getConstructors ();
```

Looping through them and when I find the right `ctor`, call:

```
ctor.Invoke (null);
```

but not sure if it works because after creating the instance, nothing is visible. I have to call the `Show` method and that's where I am stuck. I don't know how to access the created instance.

Also is this the best way to do this? It seems pretty clunky to loop through these to find the right one. Maybe this could be made better using `Linq`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try casting the result of `ctor.Invoke(null)` to the type of object you're expecting.  Here's an example (note: I'm not sure exactly what constructor your calling, so you'll need to figure out what type to cast it to, if it's not LayerView):

```
var view = (LayerView)ctor.Invoke(null);
view.Show();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ycw1y17.aspx

The `Invoke` method of `ConstructorInfo` returns an `object` reference, so you have to cast it to the type you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks but how am I gonna use the `MainWindow` type since it's defined inside the exe and I don't have it added as a reference.

Comment: I just passed the object value to type.InvokeMember, so it works. Thanks.

Comment: You could try casting it to a super type like `Window` or whatever class your view inherits from that has the Show method.